# How to read updating Log file

Tags: windows, cmd

I was wondering if there is a way/command to read the logs in window while it is getting updated at real time. My OS is windows 7.
Something similar to "tail -f *.log" in linux.

Any help would be really apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of tools mentioned in this previous post

https://serverfault.com/questions/7263/convenient-windows-equivalent-to-tail-f-logfile

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ unxutils is one

Comment: basically , it means there is no built in command for windows , right?

Comment: Let me know if there is any other option via command directly.